# Adding "PtrSafe" in few places

Tags: excel, vba

The code was showing "Complie Error" earlier and asking to update it to 64 bit so I changed and added "PtrSafe" in few places but now it is giving

> "byref argument type mismatch"

error in above code. by highlighting to boolean.

The code was earlier working fine but recently I have changed excel to Office365 in which it is not working. I don't know how to fix this. If someone can help fixing the above code? Thanks in advance.

```
Public Function Hook() As Boolean
    Dim TmpBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
    Dim p As LongPtr
    Dim OriginProtect As LongPtr

    Hook = False

    pFunc = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "DialogBoxParamA")


    If VirtualProtect(ByVal pFunc, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OriginProtect) <> 0 Then

        MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6
        If TmpBytes(0) <> &H68 Then

            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6

            p = GetPtr(AddressOf MyDialogBoxParam)

            HookBytes(0) = &H68
            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(1)), ByVal VarPtr(p), 4
            HookBytes(5) = &HC3

            MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(0)), 6
            Flag = True
            Hook = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can initially investigate the number of bytes you are moving with each Movememory statement.  In 64 bit VBA, addresses are 8 bytes (LongLong.  For further help you will need to update your question to add the Declares.

Comment: It is related to Office365 only in terms of changing the former 32 bit installation with the one on 64 bit. Only placing `PtrSafe` may not be enough. In a lot of API functions you need to also change their parameters type. You should search the internet for each API function 64 bit versions. At least, show them in your code, maybe somebody will have them already, or will do the research work instead of you...

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `PtrSafe` does not make your function work in 64-bit. The `PtrSafe` just tells VBA, "hey you are safe to use this in 64-bit as well (I made sure it works)" - the making sure it works has to be done by you. You can see documentation on compatibility here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office

The most important thing (and where your problem probably lies) is, that pointers and handles have a different size depending on if you are using 32bit or 64bit. Pointers/handles. In 32bit they should be of type `Long` in 64bit of type `LongLong` - The Type `LongPtr` assigns the type depending on if you are on 32bit or 64bit. So on 32bit `LongPtr` is `Long` on 64bit `LongLong` - So what you usually do is go through your Declare Functions, check the APIs documentation, and make sure all your pointers/handles are of type `LongPtr` - For a more in depth and more detailed explanation see the resource linked above.